# Does OpenJPA work with OSGi

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink, openjpa

The software we work on is fully on OSGi. So we need  JPA implementation which can WELL work with OSGI. Currently we use eclipselink (2.6.3)+eclipse gemini. The problem is that according to specs (jpa or osgi-ee ?) entities are not supported to be in different bundles. However, the developer of gemini said that he also doesn't understand this issue with specs and finds it strange that's why he allowed using entities from different bundles, although no special work was done.

So eclipselink somehow works with osgi. However, we came across the following problem. We have two entities: ClassA and ClassB. ClassA extends ClassB. ClassA is in one bundle, ClassB in in another bundle. We need EntityGraph (FetchGroup). EclipseLink needs weaving for FetchGroup. However, we couldn't make weaving (static and dynamic) work with our situation (it doesn't support classes be in different bundles).

So the question - can OpenJPA do what we need: entity graph + osgi support of entities?

Comment: I think you are at phase two :). Let me explain: Phase 1: Switching to OSGi, Phase 2: Feeling that something is wrong, asking questions like: how to modularize JPA, how to put entity classes into several modules. Phase 3: Switching from Java EE and Spring based monolith technologies to libraries that work well within OSGi. E.g.: Liquibase + Querydsl for persistence. Phase 4: Asking yourself, why you have ever used JPA, JSF or other technologies, even outside OSGi.

Comment: @Balazs Zsoldos To tell the truth I didn't understand the point you wanted to express. I need jpa provider in osgi, because I need jpa provider. There are 10000 libraries, but I need jpa provider.

Comment: I just wanted to give an idea why you do not get any answers to this question. Several years ago, I implemented the JPA chapter of OSGi EE spec. I really wanted to support JPA within OSGi. The thing is, they are not compatible. There are issues with every technology within OSGi that use weaving, bytecode manipulation, interceptors or other tricks. You must decide, either these technologies or OSGi otherwise you will spend your precious time on issues like this. There used to be many developers, who wanted to support JPA, but they disappeared, too. I guess, they moved forward, too.

Comment: JPA works quite well in OSGi using Aries JPA. It implements the OSGi JPA spec and is used in several high profile projects in production. 
I remember our discussion at last eclipsecon. I agree that JPA adds a lot of overhead and should be carefully considered but this is true in the same way outside of OSGi.