# Interoperability of OSGI and JPA in a JEE environment

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, osgi

We are in the process of deciding whether to use OSGI or not. It is a manifold decision however I have the specific question regarding the interoperability between OSGI and JPA. I read that there are several  problems with the combination of both. A detailed description of the issues is described in the [presentation](https://de.slideshare.net/mfrancis/enterprise-persistence-in-osgi-mike-keith-oracle) of Mike Keith or [here](http://mondula.com/2016/01/11/osgi-benefits-and-drawbacks/).

> Persistence was another challenging issue. JPA with OSGI required us
>   doubling all classes that were to be used across bundles. This forced
>   us to use interfaces for all entities, as their classes would be
>   different. The main problem here was for the developers to write the
>   correct code and to maintain the configuration files. Methods like
>   hashCode and equals usually need to be rewritten which might be 
>   non-trivial if inheritance is used for entities that exist in multiple
>   bundles.

Also I found one unanswered [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727756/does-openjpa-work-with-osgi) which described it like this:

> I just wanted to give an idea why you do not get any answers to this
>   question. Several years ago, I implemented the JPA chapter of OSGi EE
>   spec. I really wanted to support JPA within OSGi. The thing is, they
>   are **not** compatible. **There are issues with every technology within OSGi
>   that use weaving, bytecode manipulation, interceptors or other tricks.**
>   You must decide, either these technologies or OSGi otherwise you will
>   spend your precious time on issues like this. There used to be many
>   developers, who wanted to support JPA, but they disappeared, too. I
>   guess, they moved forward, too.

We use JEE 7 on JBOSS with EJBs, JPA (Hibernate), CDI and an Oracle database. We are **not** able to switch the database, the JPA provider or the persistence technology (JPA).

Comment: I honestly don't know why Mike Keith thought it necessary to double all of his classes. I haven't seen that issue and he doesn't explain in the blog post.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how well this works on JBOSS but JPA works quite well when using Aries JPA as the adapter to the OSGi specifics. The best way to use it is in Apache Karaf as it is all prepared already. So you just need to install some features.

See this for an example of using [Aries JPA with declarative services](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-ds) and [blueprint](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi).

The examples show solutions to the problems mentioned in the slides above.

- upward dependencies: Entity classes are auto detected but all Entities for a persistence unit must be in one bundle. I do notknow of any duplication needed.
- weaving: Uses hibernate proxy based weaving. Also supports compile time and load time weaving. Aries JPA takes care of weaving on bundle loading. So it happens before the application can access the classes.
- jdbc: Uses pax-jdbc-config to automatically create XA ready, pooled DataSources without classloader tricks
- JPA specification: This is solved by the OSGi JPA spec which defines how to find and sue PersistenceProviders. All current providers support this.

I saw the hint about buddy classloader .. do not use it. It will make your code non portable and more difficult to understand.

So I would say all problems with JPA in OSGi are already solved. Still JPA is much more complicated than it seems. So even though JPA works well in OSGi there are very good reasons to use a simpler persistence technology.